# Splitting a number X into groups such that their sum is always equal to X in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to split any given number, X into groups such that their sum is always equal to X in matlab ?

for example: Splitting 11 into groups of 4, the output should yield

(8,1,1,1) (7,2,1,1)  (6,3,1,1)  (6,2,2,1)   (5,4,1,1)   (5,3,2,1)   (5,2,2,2)   (4,4,2,1)   (4,3,2,2)   (4,3,3,1)   (3,3,3,2)

The sum of the numbers in each groups is 11 in each case

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One can do this using a Dynamic Programming-like idea.

What I do can be summarized as:

- Create a lookup table for how a number can be decomposed into 2 numbers
- Loop over `first_number`
- Loop over `second_number`
- Look for how `11 - first_number - second_number` can be split using look up table
- Print all such possibilities

Code:

```
%Create Loookup Table
for it=1:11
    for jt=1:11
        A(it,jt) = it+jt;
    end
end

%Find Permutations
my_perms = [];
for it=1:8
    for jt=1:8
        [my_row,my_col] = ind2sub([11,11],find(A==11-it-jt));
        num = size(my_row,1);
        my_perms = [my_perms; [it*ones(num,1) jt*ones(num,1) my_row my_col]];
    end
end
disp(my_perms)
```

Output:

```
 1     1     8     1
 1     1     7     2
 1     1     6     3
 1     1     5     4
 1     1     4     5
 1     1     3     6
 1     1     2     7
 1     1     1     8
 1     2     7     1
 1     2     6     2
 1     2     5     3
 1     2     4     4
 1     2     3     5
 1     2     2     6
 1     2     1     7
 1     3     6     1
 1     3     5     2
 1     3     4     3
 1     3     3     4
 1     3     2     5
 1     3     1     6
 1     4     5     1
 1     4     4     2
 1     4     3     3
 1     4     2     4
 1     4     1     5
 1     5     4     1
 1     5     3     2
 1     5     2     3
 1     5     1     4
 1     6     3     1
 1     6     2     2
 1     6     1     3
 1     7     2     1
 1     7     1     2
 1     8     1     1
 2     1     7     1
 2     1     6     2
 2     1     5     3
 2     1     4     4
 2     1     3     5
 2     1     2     6
 2     1     1     7
 2     2     6     1
 2     2     5     2
 2     2     4     3
 2     2     3     4
 2     2     2     5
 2     2     1     6
 2     3     5     1
 2     3     4     2
 2     3     3     3
 2     3     2     4
 2     3     1     5
 2     4     4     1
 2     4     3     2
 2     4     2     3
 2     4     1     4
 2     5     3     1
 2     5     2     2
 2     5     1     3
 2     6     2     1
 2     6     1     2
 2     7     1     1
 3     1     6     1
 3     1     5     2
 3     1     4     3
 3     1     3     4
 3     1     2     5
 3     1     1     6
 3     2     5     1
 3     2     4     2
 3     2     3     3
 3     2     2     4
 3     2     1     5
 3     3     4     1
 3     3     3     2
 3     3     2     3
 3     3     1     4
 3     4     3     1
 3     4     2     2
 3     4     1     3
 3     5     2     1
 3     5     1     2
 3     6     1     1
 4     1     5     1
 4     1     4     2
 4     1     3     3
 4     1     2     4
 4     1     1     5
 4     2     4     1
 4     2     3     2
 4     2     2     3
 4     2     1     4
 4     3     3     1
 4     3     2     2
 4     3     1     3
 4     4     2     1
 4     4     1     2
 4     5     1     1
 5     1     4     1
 5     1     3     2
 5     1     2     3
 5     1     1     4
 5     2     3     1
 5     2     2     2
 5     2     1     3
 5     3     2     1
 5     3     1     2
 5     4     1     1
 6     1     3     1
 6     1     2     2
 6     1     1     3
 6     2     2     1
 6     2     1     2
 6     3     1     1
 7     1     2     1
 7     1     1     2
 7     2     1     1
 8     1     1     1
```

Depending on your needs, you can prune this very easily.